# How to add more lights to my attic

Tags: electrical, lighting, attic, power

I have 1 light in my attic but its not bright enough for the whole attic so i want to add 4 more lights. the switch is in the downstairs hallway, so all that is in the attic is a electrical wire and the light. How would i add the 4 lights to the attic. i want all the lights to turn on when i flip the switch in the hallway. Im new to electrical work, i know to turn off the power and basic things like that but i don't know how to wire up the lights.

Comment: Adding more lights is as easy as hooking up white to white, and black to black.  Since you're asking such a basic question, I'd recommend that you buy and read through a "wiring basics" book.  Home Depot has a series of do it yourself books like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Wiring-1-2-3-Home-Depot/dp/069621184X), and I'm sure there are other good options.

Comment: @JPhi1618 And ensuring that the connections are made in approved boxes with the right size wire and grounding and stapling and wire placement and maybe the switch is a switch loop and ... Don't disagree (especially with your suggestion of research), but let's not reduce it to a one-liner.